# Prototype .Mousemove equivalent

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, compatibility, prototypejs

I would like to know if there is any equivalent to the jquery mousemove function in prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will get you where you want to be:

```
Event.observe(document, 'mousemove', callBackFunction);

callbackFunction = function(event)
{
   //do something 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer isn't prototypejs, but you could always use the DOM API directly to assign the handler.

```
document.onmousemove = function() {
    // do something
};
```

You will have good cross-browser support unless you try to place the event on `window`. So use `document` or some other element instead.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mousemove.html

To remove the handler later, assign `null`.

```
document.onmousemove = null;
```